# Python Pandas unique values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
               "IPaddress":['12.345.678.01','12.345.678.02','12.345.678.01','12.345.678.18','12.345.678.02','12.345.678.01'], 
               "score":[8,9,5,10,3,7]})
```

I'm using Python, and Pandas library. For those rows with duplicate IP addresses, I want to select only one row  with highest score (score being from 0-10), and drop all duplicates.

I'm having a difficult time in turning this logic into a Python function.

Comment: df.loc[df.groupby('IPaddress')['score'].idxmax()]

Comment: Johnny, it looks like you may be new to Stack and are wondering why you may be getting downvoted for what seems to be a "normal" question. The reason for the downvotes is that you have not posted what you have tried and it may look to some users that we are "doing your homework". In fact, this question is very similar to others on the forum. In the future, post what code you have tried. Read up on the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get a better understanding here. We wish you the best and I hope you keep coming back!

Comment: Very good point. I'll make sure to include what I've tried to the post next time. Thanks Matt

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Using the groupby function of Pandas, split the df into groups of IPaddress.

```
df.groupby('IPaddress')
```

Result of this will create an groupby object. Once you check the type of this object, it will be the following: pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy

Step 2: With the Pandas groupby object created from step1, using .idxmax() over the score, will return the Pandas series with maximum scores of each IPaddress

```
df.groupby('IPaddress').score.idxmax()
```

(Optional) Step 3: If you want to transform the above series to dataframe, you can do below:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('IPaddress').score.idxmax(),['IPaddress','score']]
```

Here, you are selecting all the rows with max scores, and showing the IPaddress, score columns.

Useful reference: 
1. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

2. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/groupby.html
3. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-idxmax/

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.